# How to download snapshot artifact from internal Nexus?

Tags: maven

I have a Nexus internal server and I defined an internal shapshot repository and the release one. Their ids are: Snapshots and Releases and they are hosted repository.

I configured a Group Repository (named Public with url http://mynexus/content/groups/public/) that contains the two described repositories (when I perform a deploy phase on a snapshot artifact then I find the artifact on the Public).

I added to my settings.xml the mirror section:

```
<mirror>
  <id>mynexus.it</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <name>My Maven Nexus Repository</name>
  <url>http://mynexus/content/groups/public/</url>
</mirror>
```

but when I perform an operation (e.g. mvn compile) which requires a snapshot artifact (which I haven't into my local repository), maven doesn't search the snapshot artifact on my nexus repository and the operation fails.

Why doesn't maven find the snapshot artifact when I execute the compile phase?

Thanks in advance.

Enrico

Comment: did i try already and fail? try "mvn -U install" to re-check snapshots. Did you verify the snapshot is actually there (using the browser for that mirror for example)?

Comment: @wemu Yes, I verified that my snapshots are into my mirror site (which is my snapshots repository).

Comment: and "mvn -U" did nothing? maven has an updatePolicy (see http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-settings/settings.html) per repository, the default ist "daily". You can reconfigure that if you need to re-check snapshots more often